# Ubuntu - how to check if Python program is running correctly from outside

Tags: python, ubuntu, infinite-loop

I have a Python script that has an infinite loop in it.

```
while True:
    doStuff()
```

Now I need to check from some external script in case the program freezes - for example if `doStuff()` was not executed for five minutes reboot the system. My idea is to save current time to a file every time `doStuff` runs and then read it from another script and if time saved in that file is 5 minutes less than now then reboot. Is there some better and more elegant solution to this?

Edit: and no - I'm not trying to check if program is running - I need to check in case it is still running but it got stuck somewhere

Comment: How about adding a `pathlib.touch()` in the loop, and check the file date?